# D3 zoom not working on current mouse coordinates after page reload

Tags: d3.js, zooming, d3-force-directed

I have a d3 Force-Directed Graph, on which I have implemented zoom functionality. My requirement is to save the current zoom attributes (scale and translate) and when the page is reloaded I have to render graph with the saved zoom attributes.

When the page is reloaded I am setting the zoom scale and translate to the previously saved values, something like this.

```
this.zoom.scale(previous-scale)
         .translate(previous-translate);
```

And then I get the scale and translate on the graph.

```
this.svgGraph.attr("transform", `translate(${previous-scale})scale(${previous-translate})`);
```

The graph is loading fine with the zoom level which was the last present.

My problem is now when I try to zoom in or zoom out the zoom operation is not happening on current mouse position as it was behaving earlier.

To set the zoom afterward I'm using

```
this.svgGraph.attr("transform", `translate(${_event.translate})scale(${_event.scale})`);
```

Does anybody knows the reason for this ??

`Note: I am using d3 v3`

Comment: can you share minimal example on http://beta.observablehq.com/, http://stackblitz.com/ or in code snippet?